# Extracting mean and variance from from a Gillespie algorithm (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, mean, variance

I'm in the process of writing a Gillespie algorithm for a simple birth-death process and I'm stuck trying to get the mean and variance from the simulation. After going through all trials (number_of_repeats), I'm trying to pull x values with my xs(time) function by returning a list of x values at a given time cutoff. I then try to find the mean and variance of this data (currently using the mean and var functions from the statistics plugin).

```
def xs(time):
    for r in range(number_of_repeats):
        x[r, (t[r, :] <= time)][-1]
for t in time_sample:
    meanx = mean(xs(t))
    variance = var(xs(t))
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
    IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-a3fafa7748b6> in <module>()
     56 
     57 for t in time_sample:
---> 58     meanx = mean(xs(t))
     59     variance = var(xs(t))
     60 

<ipython-input-38-a3fafa7748b6> in xs(time)
     49 def xs(time):
     50     for r in range(number_of_repeats):
---> 51         x[r, (t[r, :] <= time)][-1]
     52 
     53 

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

I'm by no means an expert at coding, so I'm probably making a silly mistake here. Any advice would be appreciated or corrections would be appreciated.

Edit: The (t[r,:] <= time) line should return the x value in trial r at the maximum time t that satisfies that inequality.

Comment: How is x defined?

Comment: You need to put a return statement, otherwise your function will return void. Also, what are yoi trying to do here :  (t[r, :] <= time)